# Enforce common properties on multiple interfaces

Tags: typescript

There are 2 parts of the application. The backend and the frontend. The backend has an API service, which exposes `swagger.json` which I then use to transform the C# classes to TypeScript interfaces. For transformation I use NSwag.

An example of such output is:

```
export interface RecordTypeA {
    id: string;
    dateCreated: number;

    name: string;
}

export interface RecordTypeB {
    id: string;
    dateCreated: number;

    color: string;
}
```

So this is what the client has to deal with.

Now I would like to create a generic/common interface for data manipulation on the client side. The idea here is simple - this is to allow to create generic methods in TypeScript to be able to manipulate data of any type as long as it has common properties. All types of records on the backend have following common properties (example):

```
export interface ICommonProperties {
    id: string;
    dateCreated: number;
}
```

How to enforce these properties' presence on both auto-generated interfaces?

I tried adding the following:

```
export interface RecordTypeA extends ICommonProperties {}
export interface RecordTypeB extends ICommonProperties {}
```

But to my degree of understanding this is not an enforcement of properties, but the extension. Meaning that if at some point in the future the `dateCreated` property will disappear from `RecordTypeA` (for example) - no errors will be thrown by the TypeScript compiler because the property is still present on `ICommonProperties`.

My alternative idea was somehow doing the post-transformation on top of existing transformation to transform interfaces to classes, like so:

```
export class RecordTypeA implements ICommonProperties {
    constructor(public id: string, public dateCreated: number, public name: string)
}
```

This would definitely solve my problem, but I don't know if the tools that would allow me to do it even exists? A bit of googling showed no results, except for `ts-morph` which does not seems to be suited for this kind of manipulation (changing `interface` to `class` type).

How do I enforce 2 (or more) interfaces to implement some other, generic/common interface? Or, as an alternative idea, how to convert interfaces to classes as in example above?

Comment: How does an interface "implement" another interface? Extending an interface enforces the existence of the properties and the types of that interface.

Comment: sorry I don't understand you. By extending one interface with the other we are not enforcing properties of the 'parent' interface on the 'child' interface. Properties could be defined on child but not the parent and this is the problem I am trying to solve somehow.